# Can CRM 2013 Plugin Trace Information be Obtained Client Side?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM plugins, we use the tracing service to record information:

```
localContext.Trace("Some useful info");
```

If I deliberately throw an exception in plugins, I see the trace info in the log file that I can download via the GUI.

If the plugin is being executed by API calls running on a command-line client, (creating/updating the entity that runs the plugin) and an exception is thrown, can I obtain the trace information from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to get info from client side into a plugin log? I reckon is possible to obtain those info as part of the submitting process, but you will need additional fields on the entity. 
For example you hook the plugin on the update method, you populate a multi-line text field in the entity. That field will be available on the back-end and you will be able to write in the log the content of that multi-line. Even show an Invalid plugin exception containing those information. 
Usually for debugging purposes you debug he js via UI  while, if you don't have vs on the same machine of crm you use the plugin profiler or the tracing.

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear - it's the other way around - I want server side exception info on the client! :)

Comment: You will need to write stuff anyway in a field, to be able to report it client side. If It's not a loggin that the user needs to be aware of, collect the info in a multiline text field. Also you can use a configuration entity to enable/disable the logging. This will still result in some data running into your system in addiction to the working data.

Comment: I read the post again, I think that i misunderstood you. Still the approach that I suggested is valid, from the console app write down the exception in a filed so you will be able to check it in the UI. If the plugins are asynch you will be able to check the execution status in the system jobs, if they are sychronous pre validate/operation you will be able to catch the error when you are getting the response from the service.